# Is comparing list iterators O(n)?

Tags: c++

When I compare two list iterators in C++ with say `operator<`, do I get O(n) performance because we must iterate through the whole list to see which iterator is ahead?

Or do I get O(1) performance because my compiler does something clever?

Comment: list iterators do not support `operator<`.

Comment: You should rephrase your question in terms of `std::distance` function.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, what if I use the std::distance function to compare two list iterators? Is that O(n)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get a compilation error because `list` iterators are only `BidirectionalIterator`s, and so do not support `operator<`.